# Can't connect to a postgres server

Tags: postgresql, freebsd

I have a strange situation, I have created a second postgres server that will eventually become a slave to my current master, anyway for testing purposes I have currently installed postgres, and testing connections from other hosts.

In my postgresql.conf I have a nice an easy:

`listen_addresses = '*'# what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432`

Then In my pg_hba.conf I have:

```
# allow all connections, testing only, comment in production
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

This postgres server is running in a freebsd jail, so has two IP addresses:

```
root@postgres ~# telnet 10.1.1.19 5432                     
Trying 10.1.1.19...
telnet: connect to address 10.1.1.19: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host


root@postgres ~# telnet 127.0.1.19 5432                                                                                                                                                                          1
Trying 127.0.1.19...
Connected to 127.0.1.19.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.

root@postgres ~# ifconfig                                                                                                           
em1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=4219b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWTSO>
    ether 00:25:90:27:d8:24
    inet 10.1.1.19 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 10.1.1.19 
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
lo1: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet 127.0.1.19 netmask 0xffffffff 
    groups: lo
```

So as you can see, I can on port 5432 but only using the loopback address, so then I try a simple

```
root@postgres ~# psql -h 127.0.1.19                   
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.1.19", user "root", database "root", SSL off
```

Why is this basic connection getting blocked, as my hba.conf has ALL and in addition why can I not connect via the local address of 10.1.1.19?

netstat shows the following output:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp4       0      0 127.0.1.19.postgresql  *.*                    LISTEN
```

NOTE.. I have another jail setup on another server with seemingly the same setup which works, thats on version 9.3.5 and this new server (with the issue) is on 9.6.3

EDIT: When changing config to listen on 0.0.0.0 I get a netstat output:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp4       0      0 127.0.1.19.postgresql  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0 10.1.1.19.3100         *.*                    LISTEN
```

You can see that SSH is successfully able to listen on the LAN address of 10.1.1.19 (on port 3100) so it can't be a jail networking issue, it must be something postgres related.

Comment: Have you checked your Firewall configuration?

Comment: Yes, should of stated that, disabled PF on this server for testing, and checked master network firewall, no blocked packets.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-connection.html) says about listen_addresses this:

> **listen_addresses (string)**
>
> Specifies the TCP/IP address(es) on which the server is to listen for connections from client applications. The value takes the form of
>   a comma-separated list of host names and/or numeric IP addresses. The
>   special entry * corresponds to all available IP interfaces. The entry
>   0.0.0.0 allows listening for all IPv4 addresses and :: allows listening for all IPv6 addresses. If the list is empty, the server
>   does not listen on any IP interface at all, in which case only
>   Unix-domain sockets can be used to connect to it. The default value is
>   localhost, which allows only local TCP/IP "loopback" connections to be
>   made. While client authentication (Chapter 20) allows fine-grained
>   control over who can access the server, listen_addresses controls
>   which interfaces accept connection attempts, which can help prevent
>   repeated malicious connection requests on insecure network interfaces.
>   This parameter can only be set at server start.

May be there is some bug with * as listening parameter. Try to set it to 0.0.0.0, it force postgres to listen on all IP-addresses and could fix your issue.

Comment: That made no difference.

Comment: @crooksey please show `netstat -tldpn` output with new config.

Comment: See updated orignal post @alexander-tolkachev

Answer (score 0):

After noticing all these random problems with no apparent cause, I assumed something more the one configuration file was off, I un-installed postgres, cleaned the /var/db/postgres and /usr/etc/postgres folders and then re-installed.

Everything now works as expected, so I am assuming the installation originally silently failed.